# How can I customize a data set for Google BigQuery? Can I export a file? How do I test it to see if it meets my needs?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore, google-apis-explorer

I would like to improve the quality of existing data by using the Google BigQuery API to help validate the accuracy of existing data.

I dont see information on the types of data elements contained in the BigQuery and dont understand how to use an API if I just want to see what types of data are contained in there.

I tried looking for instructions and data elements in the Google Health Care API and Google BigQuery documentation and only saw how to set up a payment option.

I am a newbie at programming and wanted to do some preliminary research on these data sets prior to bringing them to our technical team.

I expect to see a list of relevant results based on a custom query.

Comment: Are you importing Cloud Datastore data into BigQuery or something else?  If so, the type conversions are documented at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore#data_type_conversion .

Comment: thank you I will check it out...

Answer (score 1):

You can see the data types supported 
 by Google BigQuery [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types) and the conversion between different types [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules).

Also you can try out the BigQuery APIs in the [OAuthPlayGround](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).